# Savon::SoapFault: Unexpected character '>' (code 62) (expected a name start character)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wsdl, savon

I am trying to understand the [Railscast: SOAP with Savon](http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon) and implement it for my scenario.

I have executed the following in `rails console`

```
realm = Base64.strict_encode64("user:password")

client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://xxxxx?wsdl", soap_header: { 'Authorization:' => "Basic #{realm}"}, log: true, log_level: :debug, pretty_print_xml: true)

message = {"X1" => "XX", "X2" => 108539, "X3" => 2, "CONFIRM" => TRUE}
```

All fine so far. The following line is throwing an error

```
response = client.call(:update_job, message: message)
```

Please can you let me know how to resolve the following error or any useful documentation that I can look at to fix the error. (I have tried searching online and also looked at http://savonrb.com/version2/requests.html)

```
HTTPI POST request to sit (net_http)
SOAP response (status 500)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd=
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-i
nstance">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Unexpected character '&gt;' (code 62) (expected a name start
character)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,434]</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Savon::SOAPFault: (soap:Server) Unexpected character '>' (code 62) (expected a n
ame start character)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,434]
        from c:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/savon-2.6.0/lib/savon/res
ponse.rb:85:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/savon-2.6.0/lib/savon/res
ponse.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/savon-2.6.0/lib/savon/ope
ration.rb:64:in `create_response'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/savon-2.6.0/lib/savon/ope
ration.rb:55:in `call'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/savon-2.6.0/lib/savon/cli
ent.rb:36:in `call'
        from (irb):75:in `evaluate'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in `eval'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1501:in `loop'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails
/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails
/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails
/commands.rb:41:in `(root)'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `(root)'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your soap_header should not be postfixed with `:` (`Authorization:`).

```
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "http://xxxxx?wsdl", 
  soap_header: { 'Authorization' => "Basic #{realm }"}, 
  log: true, 
  log_level: :debug, 
  pretty_print_xml: true
)
```

http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I receive the following error after I have removed it.       <faultstring>WSS4JInHandler: Request does not contain required Security header</faultstring>

Comment: Well thats impossible to resolve without knowing the details of the SOAP web service you are communicating with.

Comment: I would recommend you start a new question with that information.